# What does client send after receiving a "100 Continue" status code?

Tags: http, http-headers

Client sends a POST or PUT request that includes the header:

```
Expect: 100-continue
```

The server responds with the status code:

```
100 Continue
```

What does the client send now?  Does it send an entire request (the previously send request line and headers along with the previously NOT sent content)?  Or does it only send the content?

I think it's the later, but I'm struggling to find concrete examples online.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.2.3) *should* be all the information you need regarding the usage of a `100 Continue` response.

In my experienced this is really used when you have a large request body. It could be considered to be roughly complementary to the HEAD method in relation to GET requests - fetch just the header information and not the body (usually) to reduce network load. 100 responses are used to determine whether the server will accept the request based purely on the headers - so that, for example, if you try and send a large POST/PUT request to a non-existent server resource it will result in a 404 *before* the entire request body has been sent.

So the short answer to your question is - yes, it's the latter. Although, you should always read the RFC for a complete picture. [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) contains 99% of the information you would ever need to know about HTTP - there are some more recent RFCs that settle some ambiguities and offer a few small extensions to the protocol but off the top of my head I can't remember what they are.